# JSON Parsing Error with HTTP Status Code 204

Tags: php, json, rest

This is a weird scenario I came across while developing a `RESTful API`. Whenever I send a `HTTP Status Code 204` along with a `JSON` encoded `array` to show the message, my REST `client` (*at this moment, it is a Google Chrome extension*), shows me an error of '`Malformed JSON`'. If I change the status code to something else, the client shows the JSON just fine.
I'm new-ish to the `REST API` but this still seems like a weird thing to me.

Comment: Ummm...Status Code 204 means "No Content".  I doubt your client even tries to read the body of the message, and just assumes it's empty.

Comment: Why do you think it's weird for something that expects content, but gets a "No Content" status code, to then issue an error about not getting what it expects?

Comment: So what you're saying is, it is completely fine to receive this error on the client end?
Moreover, would I have to check for a 204 status code explicitly on the actual client (my mobile app) for every request it is expected to be returned in?

Comment: The question is, why do you want to send a status code 204 when it's actually a 200 ?

Comment: A 200 entails that the request was successful and client should expect whatever it was requesting. But in my case, exception may occur and the client may not get any data at all. Case in point: payment history of a n account number that hasn't performed any sort of activity.

Comment: @BasitSaeed You're new to this and you're writing an app that handles payment data?  Maybe not your best choice for a first application...

Comment: It was just a 'for instance' example :)

Comment: @BasitSaeed Haha, ok, sorry  :)

Comment: @BasitSaeed Good luck with your project!

Comment: @CullyLarson No problem! I wasn't clear it was a hypothetical situation. Thank you for your responses :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**204 Status Code Explained**

The 204 status code means that the request was received and understood, but that there is no need to send any data back.

**Why it Occurs**

The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation. The response MAY include new or updated metainformation in the form of entity-headers, which if present, SHOULD be associated with the requested variant.The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

**What it Means**

If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view from that which caused the request to be sent. This response is primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place without causing a change to the user agent's active document view, although any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to the document currently in the user agent's active view.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. It clears a lot of things up. I don't suppose I need to send an additional meta information in the headers. I'd explicitly check for a 204 status code on my client and form the message to be shown to user there.